# Compiling PHP 5.1.6 with PDO MySQL

Tags: mysql, php, configuration, pdo

**UPDATE**

I Asked this over on StackOverflow as I hadn't got any answers on here at the time.
[Here's the link to the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164345/compiling-php-5-1-6-with-pdo-mysql) for completeness' sake. I'll like that page back over here once I've tried Dan C's solution below.

---

**ORIGINAL**

A while ago a large client of ours moved to a single hosting provider who spec'd out a software environment which would be consistent accross all the live servers.

Amongs other things this includes Apache 2.2.8 and PHP 5.1.6.

We had an ubuntu 8.04 server for development and these versions of Apache and PHP are not the default installed. So I had to compile them from source.
These versions have happily been running for over a year now.

We're starting a new site build and we want to use ZendFrameword which requires PDO_MySQL.

I've tried recompiling with the following...

```
./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs \
--with-config-file-path=/user/local/apache2/conf/php.ini \
--with-curl=/usr/lib/ --with-mysql=shared --with-mysqli=shared \
--with-zlib --with-gd --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/lib/ \
--with-freetype-dir=/usr/lib/ --enable-soap --enable-pdo=shared \
--with-pdo-mysql=shared --with-sqlite=shared
...
make
...
make install
...
libtool --finish /sources/php-5.1.6/libs
```

Which all works fine, and when I bring apache back up, it shows me the new ./configure in the phpinfo().

After doing this MySQL stops working, the MYSQL section disappears and msyql stops working.

The make, make install, libtool... puts the *.so files in

/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20050922

The configure I have used previously which enabled MySQL but not PDO is

```
./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs \
--with-config-file-path=/user/local/apache2/conf/php.ini \
--with-curl=/usr/lib/ --with-mysql --with-mysqli \
--with-zlib --with-gd --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/lib/ \
--with-freetype-dir=/usr/lib/ --enable-soap
```

I'm not a massive *nix person, can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:**

You have an extraneous "e" in your `--with-config-file-path` flag.

If the typo's in your real `configure` too then it could be a cause of your problem.

**Second:**

PHP needs to know where to load the extension from.

You can tell it to search the directory you've noted by editing your `php.ini` as follows:

```
extension_dir = "/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20050922/"
```

**Just of note:**

Backslashes are the common notation for line continuations.

Your shell will interpret them safely if you copy/paste a command to the terminal.

Comment: Thanks for the backslashes tip. Also, good spot on the "user" and I'll give the extension_dir a whirl.